# Android instrumentation.callActivityOnPause causes "System services not available to Activities before onCreate()"

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-activity, android-testing

I'm currently setting up unit test to test my camera app where I release the camera handle when the app goes into the background via the onPause callback. As soon as it gets up to the part where I call the onPause method of the activity I'd get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:4738)
at android.app.Activity.getMultiWindowStyle(Activity.java:4563)
at android.app.Activity.getMultiWindowStyle(Activity.java:4568)
at android.app.Activity.onPause(Activity.java:1366)
at com.ricky.chow.cameraopencv.activity.MainCameraActivity.onPause(MainCameraActivity.java:57)
at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5555)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1239)
at com.ricky.chow.cameraopencv.activity.MainCameraActivityTest.tearDownThisActivity(MainCameraActivityTest.java:58)
at com.ricky.chow.cameraopencv.activity.MainCameraActivityTest.testCameraPreviewExists(MainCameraActivityTest.java:78)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1729)
```

Unit test:

```
public class MainCameraActivityTest extends ActivityUnitTestCase<MainCameraActivity> {

private Intent mLaunchIntent;
private ImageButton captureButton;
private FrameLayout cameraPreviewView;
private Instrumentation mInstrumentation;
private MainCameraActivity mActivity;
public MainCameraActivityTest(Class<MainCameraActivity> activityClass) {
    super(activityClass);
}
public MainCameraActivityTest() {
    super(MainCameraActivity.class);
}


private void setUpThisActivity()
{
    mLaunchIntent = new Intent(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(),
            MainCameraActivity.class);
    mInstrumentation = getInstrumentation();
    mActivity = startActivity(mLaunchIntent, null, null);

    mInstrumentation.callActivityOnStart(mActivity);
    mInstrumentation.callActivityOnResume(mActivity);
    captureButton = (ImageButton)mActivity.findViewById(R.id.CaptureButton);
    cameraPreviewView = (FrameLayout)mActivity.findViewById(R.id.CameraPreview);
}

private void tearDownThisActivity()
{
    mInstrumentation.callActivityOnPause(mActivity);
    mInstrumentation.callActivityOnStop(mActivity);
}

public void testCameraPrieviewWorks()
{
    setUpThisActivity();
    MedianCameraPost mMedianCam = (MedianCameraPost) cameraPreviewView.getChildAt(0);
    Assert.assertNotNull(mMedianCam);
    Assert.assertEquals(mMedianCam.getVisibility(), View.VISIBLE);
    tearDownThisActivity();
}
```

}

Comment: I have the same issue